# How to select text in columns in a table

Tags: html, html-table, selection

Is there anyway to get the text on an HTML table to be selectable like the tables in MS Word? In a normal html table, when the user selects text using the mouse, the text is selected in ROWS. In MS Word, it is selected in COLUMNS. I am using IE8 in standard mode. I don't mind if the solution uses script or css.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer to your previous question, which says that IE doesn't support multiple selection, implies that the answer to this question is "No."

Comment: You *could* change the content type to Word, but it relies on the user having Word/Office installed...

Comment: Yes, any number of solutions of you're not using IE, or if you're using an IE add-in instead of IE's HTML renderer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use script and css, then you could:

- Define a CSS rule, associated with a class, which looks like (e.g. is colored like) the text is selected
- Track mouse events (using the DOM event API)
- Using script attached to mouse events, dynamically set the class attribute of table cells (to make it *seem* selected, using the CSS rule)

I haven't tested this! It's just an idea (not necessarily a good idea; but an answer to your question as stated).